# Add Items To a existing List In a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary as below

```
var dicAclWithCommonDsEffectivity = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
```

I have a list as below

```
var dsList=new List<int>();
```

For each item in `dsList` I will search in `dicAclWithCommonDsEffectivity` dictionary for the matching values in the list. If i find a match I take its Keys and form a new Key combining all the keys. I will create a new list and add item.

```
foreach (int i in dsList)
{
    var aclWithmatchingDS = dicAclWithCommonDsEffectivity.Where(x => x.Value.Contains(i)).Select(x=>x.Key);
    if (aclWithmatchingDS.Count() > 0)
    {
        string NewKey= aclWithmatchingDS.key1+","aclWithmatchingDS.key2 ;

        //if NewKey is not there in dictionary 
        var lst=new List<int>(){i};
        //Add item to dictionary
        //else if item is present append item to list
        //oldkey,{oldlistItem,i};

    }
}
```

For the next item in dsList if there is a matching key then I have to add the item to the list inside new dictionary.

How to add new item to the list in a dictionary without creating new list.

Answer (score 6):

You probably want something like that:

```
if (dicAclWithCommonDsEffectivity.ContainsKey(NewKey))
{
    dicAclWithCommonDsEffectivity[NewKey].Add(i)
}
else
{
    dicAclWithCommonDsEffectivity.Add(NewKey, lst); // or simply do new List<int>(){ i } instead of creating lst earlier 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Get first `KeyValue` pair in `dicAclWithCommonDsEffectivity`and add it to the list, which is the value here and it can be accessed directly:

```
 if (aclWithmatchingDS.Count() > 0)
 {
   dicAclWithCommonDsEffectivity.Add(NewKey,lst);
 }
 else
 {
    aclWithmatchingDS.First().Value.Add("Here add your item");
 }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest `TryGetValue` method which is typical in such cases:

```
List<int> list;

if (dicAclWithCommonDsEffectivity.TryGetValue(NewKey, out list))
  list.Add(i);
else
  dicAclWithCommonDsEffectivity.Add(NewKey, new List<int>() {i});
```

In case of *C# 7.0* you can get rid of `list` declaration:

```
if (dicAclWithCommonDsEffectivity.TryGetValue(NewKey, out var list))
  list.Add(i);
else
  dicAclWithCommonDsEffectivity.Add(NewKey, new List<int>() {i});
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me clarify before suggestion, So You want to check for existance of a key in the dictionary, according to some condition, If specific key is present means you want to add the new item to corresponding key or else you want to create a new key and a new list with the new item, if I understand the requirement correctly means you can try the following:

```
if(dicAclWithCommonDsEffectivity.ConainsKey(NewKey))
{
    aclWithmatchingDS[NewKey].Add(i);
}
else
{
    aclWithmatchingDS.Add(NewKey, new List<int>(){i});
}
```

Comment: I want to create a new key suing the present dictionary key and a new list with the new item. This new and and new list should be added to new dictionary.